# Convergence of matrix with spectral radius 1

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, spectral-radius

The following matrix:

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}  \\ \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ 
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\ 
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} $$

has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1,\lambda_2=-\frac{1}{3},\lambda_3=-\frac{1}{3},\lambda_4=-\frac{1}{3}$. So, $ \lambda_1 $ is the spectral radius. I know that a matrix with a spectral radius $< 1$ converges to $0$ and with a spectral radius $> 1$ to infinity. How can I prove to which value a matrix with spectral radius of $1$ converges?

I found theorem 8 in [these slides](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emath211/m211oh/m211oh93.pdf) but don't quite understand how to apply it in the case of the above matrix.

So in other words:

The theorem states that the matrix converges to the lowest order constituent matrix, but not sure how to find this matrix?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "a [one and only] matrix converges" ?

Comment: Just checking you want to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} M^n = 0$ right?

Comment: You need to check that $1$ is a regular, dominant eigenvalue. You found all the eigenvalues, so $1$ is obviously a dominant eigenvalue. But it's also a simple eigenvalue, in which case the condition $\nu_A(1) = m_A(1)$ is fulfilled : both are equal to $1$. Therefore, the theorem applies in this case. I'm not writing this as an answer because this could be a duplicate.

Comment: You can decompose $M$ into $M = P J P^{-1} $ by finding the eigenvalues / eigenvectors.  Then you have $M^n = P J^n P^{-1} $ .  Find the limit of $J^n$ as $n \to \infty$, and this will give you the limit of $M^n$

Comment: Hi all, just to be clear: I want to know how prove that 1) a matrix with a spectral radius of 1 converges to some value (as the theorem in the link states) 2) how to find this value. The theorem states that the matrix converges to the lowest order constituent matrix, but not sure how to find this matrix.

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea: The problem here is, that M has no distinct eigenvalues and so I there is no guarantee that the inverse of P exists (see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329769/eigendecomposition-does-the-eigenvectors-matrix-always-have-an-inverse). In this case P is singular

Comment: @holistic If $P$ is not invertible, then find one $P$ that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing a Jordan decomposition for this matrix gives

$$M=VJV^{-1}$$

where

$$V=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} -\frac{1}{16} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{15}{16} & -1\\ -\frac{1}{16} & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{1}{16} & 0\\ -\frac{1}{16} & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{17}{16} & 0\\ -\frac{1}{16} & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{1}{16} & 1 \end{array}\right),\ V^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} -4 & -5 & -3 & -4\\ -3 & 9 & -3 & -3\\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)$$

and

$$J=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} \end{array}\right).$$

Clearly, we have that

$$M^n=(VJV^{-1})^n=VJ^nV^{-1}$$

where

$$J^n=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n & n\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n \end{array}\right).$$

Therefore, when $n\to\infty$,

$$J^n\to J^*:=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).$$

As a result,

$$M^n\to VJ^*V^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{16}\\-\frac{1}{16}\\-\frac{1}{16}\\-\frac{1}{16}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -4 & -5 & -3 & -4\end{pmatrix}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{16} & \frac{3}{16} & \frac{1}{4}\\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{16} & \frac{3}{16} & \frac{1}{4}\\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{16} & \frac{3}{16} & \frac{1}{4}\\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{16} & \frac{3}{16} & \frac{1}{4} \end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @holistic The method is general as long as the there is one simple eigenvalue at 1 and the others are inside the unit disc. The case where multiple eigenvalues are on the unit circle is more delicate and more assumptions are needed for convergence.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining why the element in row 2, column 3 in $J^n$ is $n(-1/3)^{n-1}$? Not quite clear to me

Comment: Just calculate $J^2$ and $J^3$ and see how this entry evolves.

Comment: ah of course, I missed that. It is clear now, thanks again :)!

Answer (score 0):

$M$ can be decomposed into

$$ M = P J P^{-1} $$

where

$ J = \begin{bmatrix} - \frac{1}{3} && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && - \frac{1}{3} && 1 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && - \frac{1}{3} && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

and

$ P = \begin{bmatrix} -2 && \frac{1}{4} && \frac{5}{4} && 1 \\ 1 && -\frac{1}{12} && 1 && 1 \\
1 && - \frac{1}{12} && 0 && 1 \\
0 && - \frac{1}{12} && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

One can easily verify that

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} J^n = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

and we also have

$ P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 1 && -1 \\
3 && \frac{15}{4} && \dfrac{9}{4} && -9 \\
0 && 1 && -1 && 0 \\
\frac{1}{4} && \frac{5}{16} && \frac{3}{16} && \frac{1}{4} \end{bmatrix} $

Hence,

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} M^n = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4} && \frac{5}{16} && \frac{3}{16} && \frac{1}{4} \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4} && \frac{5}{16} && \frac{3}{16} && \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{4} && \frac{5}{16} && \frac{3}{16} && \frac{1}{4} \\\frac{1}{4} && \frac{5}{16} && \frac{3}{16} && \frac{1}{4} \\\frac{1}{4} && \frac{5}{16} && \frac{3}{16} && \frac{1}{4} \end{bmatrix} $